# localization bootstrap-Table not displaying as wanted

Tags: django, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-table

Im using the following code:

Based on the browser language i change up the locale
Even if the browser fex is en-US its get defaulted to dutch

```
     <script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.18.3/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap-table-nl-BE.js'%}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap-table-fr-BE.js'%}"></script>
    <script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
        var userLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
        if (userLang == "fr" || userLang == "fr-FR" || userLang == "fr-BE") {
            language = "fr-BE"
        } else {
            language = "nl-BE"
        }
        $("#table").bootstrapTable({
            locale : language,

        })
     } )   

</script>
```

But even when the browser is in en-US it keeps displaying in French.

Comment: You never declared `language` in your scope (with `var language` or even better with `let language`), so it is set in the global scope. This can lead to issues with some other script already using it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. but it does not work :(